# Restoring Maths Confidence

Tags: soft-question, contest-math, self-learning, advice, learning

As part of training for mathematical olympiads, I've started looking into a lot of more advanced mathematics. I love maths, but recently, I feel like my confidence has plummeted. I can't work on problems for nearly as long as I need to. I give up way too fast and I don't know how to change that.

I would really, really appreciate any advice anyone has on how to get out of this situation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We have a tag called `soft-question` while also a reason for closing called `opinion-based`. This is a somewhat strange situation...

Comment: @WhatsUp: I think that's not strange at all. Among questions whose answers "can't be objectively evaluated as true or false" (definition of the soft-question tag), there is a wide spectrum from some that are focussed, relate to mathematical concepts and whose answers will contain objective information --- to some that are very broad, are not specifically math-related, and whose answers will mostly consist of hearsay, opinions and anecdotal evidence. Of course there's a grey area in the middle, but the ones close to the first end of the spectrum are welcome, the others not so much.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Nevertheless, whether a question is "close to the first end of the spectrum" is `opinion-based`...

Comment: @Whatsup: Well, if somebody were to ask a question (A) on math.stackexchange about whether another question (B) on math.stackexchange is opinion-based, I would vote to close question (A).

Comment: (Preface: I know this is off topic for math.se, and also this may or may not apply to OP. I just want to put this out there in case it helps OP or anyone in a similar situation.) 

From personal experience, I have problems with shaming myself and feeling like I am "not good enough". This causes me many problems, one of which is similar to OP's: if I struggle to solve a question and I feel like I "should" have solved it already, then I start to feel desperate and ashamed and want to give up. [...]

Comment: [...] I have found that self-negativity is both harmful to my mental health and counterproductive. It causes me to do worse at whatever I'm trying to improve. In general, a person can improve without feeling bad about themself. But it is often difficult to stop the self-negativity because it is deeply entrenched in many cultures that one _should_ feel bad about oneself if they aren't "enough". [...]

Comment: [...] Personally, I have made progress on this by recognizing these feelings explicitly and imagining what I would say to my friend, if they were in my situation. I probably wouldn't tell them to feel bad about their (lack of) progress on a problem, so why should I tell myself that? This is a technique my therapist taught me. If you find that this kind of thing is affecting other areas of your life too, talking to a therapist may help you as well.